# 2 requests in only one using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two requests

**UPDATE :**

I need to do something like that :

```
SELECT poste_nom, ups_type_contrat, 
(SELECT  `entpro_date` 
FROM ENT_PRO
WHERE entpro_user_id = 2
ORDER BY  `entpro_id` DESC 
LIMIT 1) ,
serv_nom, 
serv_id_resp, 
user_credit_cpf, 
user_indice_salarial,
FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , user_dateentree ) /365 ) AS dateEntree 
FROM USER 
INNER JOIN USER_POSTE_SERVICE 
ON USER.user_id= USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id  
INNER JOIN POSTE 
ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE. ups_poste_id = POSTE.poste_id 
INNER JOIN SERVICE 
ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_id_serv = SERVICE.serv_id
WHERE user_id = 2
ORDER BY user_nom ASC
```

Is it possible to gather two requests in only one ?

Comment: It is not clear how these two requests would be related, can you illustrate with a little data sample please?

Comment: i've updated my post

Comment: yes it changes, it's normally :idSalarie and ys it's from any column from the others tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you want to simple merge the result of your sub-query to your main SELECT, if so you could try it this way:

```
    SELECT poste_nom, 
           ups_type_contrat, 
           ENT_PRO_RESULT.entpro_date,
           serv_nom, 
           serv_id_resp, 
           user_credit_cpf, 
           user_indice_salarial,
           FLOOR( DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , user_dateentree ) /365 ) AS dateEntree 
      FROM USER
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT entpro_date,
                   entpro_user_id
              FROM ENT_PRO
          ORDER BY entpro_id DESC 
             LIMIT 1) ENT_PRO_RESULT
        ON USER.user_id = ENT_PRO_RESULT.entpro_user_id
INNER JOIN USER_POSTE_SERVICE
        ON USER.user_id = USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id
INNER JOIN POSTE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_poste_id = POSTE.poste_id 
INNER JOIN SERVICE 
        ON USER_POSTE_SERVICE.ups_id_serv = SERVICE.serv_id
     WHERE user_id = 2
  ORDER BY user_nom ASC
```

I've joined it on:

```
ON USER.user_id = ENT_PRO_RESULT.entpro_user_id
```

So you only need to specify the:

```
WHERE user_id = 2
```

And the sub-query will use the current row user id for the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: yes, i need to include the result off me query 2, in my query 1, in order to get only 1 select. i've tried your request but i have the same result between mine and your

Comment: oh no that's ok my subquery was wrong, it's working, thank you ;)